# Not able to understand the why register method is not being called after prepare. always customeraction-validation.xml is being called

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, tiles

I am developing a sample web application in struts2. But i am getting some weird behaviour

**CustomerAction.java:**

```
package com.astro.action;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import com.astro.model.*;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.SkipValidation;

//import org.hibernate.classic.Validatable;

import com.astro.base.framework.AstroSystemException;
import com.astro.bo.CustomerBo;
import com.astro.model.Customer;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Validateable;

public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport implements  Serializable,SessionAware,Preparable, ModelDriven<CustomerPageInfo>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2335707118972931221L;

    private Map<String,Object> session;
    String target = "";
    //DI via Spring

    private CustomerPageInfo model;
    private CustomerBo customerBo;
    private Customer customer=new Customer();
    public CustomerBo getCustomerBo() {
        return customerBo;
    }
    public void setCustomerBo(CustomerBo customerBo) {
        this.customerBo = customerBo;
    }

    public String errorDisplay()
    {
        return "input";
    }
    //Register a Customer
            public String register() throws Exception{
                System.out.println("I am in register method of CustomerAction.java");
                System.out.println("((())))"+model.getCountryList().toString());
                System.out.println("((())))"+model.getCustomerInfo());
                model.getCustomerInfo().setCreatedDate(new Date());
                 customerBo.register(customer);
                return SUCCESS;
                }

    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        if(model==null)
        {
            model=new CustomerPageInfo();
            System.out.println("In prepare method");
            if(model.getCountryList()==null)
            {
                List<NameValuePair> countryList=customerBo.getAllCountries();
                model.setCountryList(countryList);
            }
            System.out.println("Before initializing"+model.getCustomerInfo());
            if(model.getCustomerInfo()==null)
            {
                model.setCustomerInfo(customer);
            }
            System.out.println("After initializing"+model.getCustomerInfo());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.session=map;
    }

    /*public void validate()
    {
        try {
            if(customerBo.doesCustomerExists(customer)==true)
            {
                addActionError("Customer Alreay Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                addActionMessage(INPUT);
            }
        } catch (AstroSystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
*/
    public void setModel(CustomerPageInfo model)
    {

    this.model=model;
    }

    public CustomerPageInfo getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
    <!-- <constant name="struts.freemarker.mru.max.strong.size" value="250" /> -->
    <constant name="struts.freemarker.templatesCache.updateDelay"
        value="60000" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />

    <package name="astro" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <!-- Different types of result types -->
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

        <interceptors>
                <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="params">
                  <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>

        </interceptors>
         <action name="registerCustomer" class="customerAction" method="register"> 
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">successInformation</param>
            </result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/registration.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="successInformation" class="com.astro.action.DisplayAction"
            method="display">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/regSuccess.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="loginCustomer" class="loginAction" method="login">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/loginSuccess.tiles</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/loginForm.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="loginCustomer1" class="loginAction" method="logout">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/loginForm.tiles</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/loginForm.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="login" class="com.astro.action.DisplayAction1"
            method="display">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/loginForm.tiles</result>
        </action>
        <action name="feedback" class="com.astro.action.DisplayAction1"
            method="display1">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/contact.tiles</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/contact.tiles</result>
        </action>
        <action name="contactus" class="contactAction" method="contact">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/contactus.tiles</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/contactsuccess.tiles
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

**customer.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(css/main.css);
</style>
<style>
.errorMessage {
    color: red;
}
.errors {
    background-color:#FFCCCC;
    border:1px solid #CC0000;
    width:400px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    font: message-box;
}
.errors li{ 
    list-style: none; 
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.errorsBg{
    background-color:;
    color:black;    
    border: 0px solid;
}

.errorMessage{
    padding:4px 8px;
}

 table{
    border-spacing: 8px;
} 
td{
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<script>
/* $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keydown(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color","yellow");
  });
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color","pink");
  });
}); */
</script>
</head>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="green">
    <!-- <h1>Welcome to Astro vedic</h1>
    <h2>Register a Customer</h2> -->
    <div class="errors" style="width: 500px">
    <s:token></s:token>
    </div>
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
   <div class="errors">
      <s:actionerror/>
   </div>
</s:if>
<s:form action="registerCustomer.do" focusElement="focus" method="post" validate="true" namespace="/">
<s:actionerror /> 
            <s:textfield id="focus" name="name" key="name" size="20" />
            <s:password name="password" label="Password "/>
            <s:password name="confirmPassword" label="Re-enter Password "/>
            <s:textfield name="email" key="email" size="20" required="true" />
             <s:textfield name="telephone" key="telephone" size="20"></s:textfield> 
            <s:select required="true" name="countryCode" label="CountryName" listValue="name" headerKey="" headerValue="Choose One"
            list="countryList" listKey="value"/>  
            <s:submit align="center" key="addCustomer"/>

        </s:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i am running the code its going to prepare method but not to register method. Not only that if i remove customerAction-validation.xml then its going to register method but nothing is saved in db.

Prepare method is called twice. I am not understanding how to call the register method and customer details get saved.

Comment: If you don't put Java tag, Java code snippets won't be syntax-highlighted ;)

Answer (score 1):

In `prepare()` you check for `model`;

`model` will be set by **Params Interceptor** (**ModelDriven Interceptor** should be involved too, not sure how because I've never used *ModelDriven*), that runs later than **Prepare Interceptor**, as you can see in your `defaultStack` definition;

You need to use a stack named **paramsPrepareParamsStack**, that includes two times the **Params Interceptor**, one before and one after the **Prepare Interceptor**, for letting the `prepare()` method to work with parameters (*model* or not) coming from the page.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html

> An example of the **paramsPrepareParams** trick. This stack
>    is exactly the same as the defaultStack, except that it
>    includes one extra interceptor before the prepare interceptor:
>    the params interceptor.
>
> This is useful for when you wish to apply parameters directly
>        to an object that you wish to load externally (such as a DAO
>        or database or service layer), but can't load that object
>        until at least the ID parameter has been loaded. By loading
>        the parameters twice, you can retrieve the object in the
>        prepare() method, allowing the second params interceptor to
>        apply the values on the object.